# execute three function simultaneously

Tags: php, multithreading, simple-html-dom

I have sript php with three function like this:

```
public function a($html,$text)
{
    //blaa
return array();
}
public function b($html,$text){
    //blaa
return array();
}
public function c($html,$text){
    //blaa
return array();
}
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$a=array();
$html=new simple_html_dom();
$a=$this->a($html,$text);
$b=$this->b($html,$text);
$c=$this->c($html,$text);
$html->clear();
unset($html);
$a=array_merge($a, $c);
$a=array_merge($a, $b);
```

- `a($html,$text)` takes 5 seconds before giving a result
- `b($html,$text)` takes 10 seconds before giving a result
- `c($html,$text)` takes 12 seconds before giving a result

Thus the system takes 27 seconds before geving me a result, but I want take my result in 12 seconds. I can't use threads because my hosting does not support threads. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: PHP is not a multi-threaded language. Either run 3 parallel PHP scripts (which will basically be independent of each other), or be resigned to having to run your three dom operations serially.

Comment: Are you actually sure that you server would serve you faster if it was working in parallell?

Comment: yes because every function I make a call to a deferent website

Comment: @MarcB How i can run 3 parallel php script in my web hosting with one script php?

Comment: You create 3 seperate php files and invoke their execution by a function like file_get_contents or with cURL, then read their output.

Comment: Using file_get_contents or curl just creates an extra layer of problems @Shocked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the wait time is caused by blocking IO (waiting for server response) then curl_multi might help.

From the code you posted, though, it doesn't look like is your problem.

It looks more like simple html dom is taking a long time to parse your html. That's not too surprising because it's not a very good library. If this is the case you should consider switching to DomXPath.

Answer (score 4):

PHP does not support this out of the box. If you really want to do this, you have two basic options (yep, it's going to be dirty). If you want a serious solution depending on your actual use-case, there is another option to consider.

**Option 1: Use some AJAX-trickery**
Create a page with a button that triggers three AJAX-calls to the different functions that you want to call.

**Option 2: Run a command**
If you're on UNIX, you can trigger a command from the PHP script to run a PHP script (php xyz.php) and that actually runs it on a different thread.

**Serious option: use queues**
Seriously: use a queue system like rabbitMQ or BeanstalkD to do these kind of things. Laravel supports it out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna look into jQuery deferred objects.... $.when should handle this kinda of situation.